# how do i run this jquery function on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this makes the back to top div appear when scrolling down 100 pixels, but if a person is already scrolled down and does a refresh, the page stays scrolled down, but the div is not shown.

```
<div id="gototopwrap"><a href="#t" id="gototop">Back To Top</a></div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {              
      $('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
    });
});
</script>
```

i tried doing this, but it didn't work:

```
$(function myFunction(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {              
    $('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
  });
});
myFunction();
```

also tried it like this, and still nothing:

```
function myFunction(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {              
    $('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
  });
}
myFunction();
```

i'm already wrapping in document ready.  i think the issue is that it's only listening for the the scroll and only acts on scroll.

Comment: Your `$(window).scroll` part is just adding an event handler, the code inside that handler isn't run until the scroll event is fired. So what you need to do on load is run just the body of that function. i.e. `$('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind both events:

```
$(window).on('load scroll', function() {              
  $('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Trigger the event which will fire your function

```
$(window).scroll(function() {              
  $('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
}).trigger("scroll");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {              
      $('#gototopwrap').toggle($(document).scrollTop() > 100);
    });
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 100)
    {

        $('#gototopwrap').toggle();

    }
});
```